# Efficiently counting '1' bits in the first n bits

Tags: optimization, c, performance, bitwise

I have two functions to count the number of set '1' bits in the first `offset` bits of either a 64 bit number, or a bitmap struct.

After some profiling, particularly the latter is quite a bottleneck in our system.

What can we do to make it faster?

```
#define POPCOUNT16(x) __builtin_popcount(x)
#define POPCOUNT64(x) __builtin_popcountl(x)

static __always_inline __constant int32 count64(int64 const bitmap, int32 const offset) {
    return offset == 0 ? 0 : POPCOUNT64(bitmap & (0xffffffffffffffffUL << (64 - offset)));
}

typedef struct {
    int64 hi;
    int16 lo;
} __packed int80;

static __always_inline __constant int32 countBitmap(int80 const bitmap, int32 const offset) {
    int32 count = 0;
    if (offset > 0) {
        count += POPCOUNT64(bitmap.hi & (0xffffffffffffffffUL << (sizeof (bitmap.hi)*8 - MIN(offset, sizeof (bitmap.hi)*8))));
        if (offset > sizeof (bitmap.hi)*8)
            count += POPCOUNT16(bitmap.lo & ((int16)0xffff << (sizeof (bitmap.hi)*8+sizeof (bitmap.lo)*8 - offset)));
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Either I'm confused, or you are. `count64()` takes an `int64 bitmap` — how can there be a `bitmap.hi`?

Comment: can you guarantee that offset is larger than 0? if so you can eliminate the first branch

Comment: @ratchetfreak Either I have the branch at the call site, or in the function. As it's marked with `inline __attribute__((always_inline))`, I figured it would make no difference which, so I put it in the function for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

first issue: you hardcode `8` as the number of bits per `sizeof` unit: portability says it should be `CHAR_BIT` which may be something else on some architectures

second issue: both members of int80 are signed, only `hi` should be while `lo` can be unsigned

if you can guarantee that offset is between 0 and 80 then you don't need to test for 0, and just document that exceeding the bounds is undefined behavior

```
static __always_inline __constant int32 countBitmap(int80 const bitmap, uint32 const offset) {
    int32 count = 0;
    if (offset <= sizeof (bitmap.hi)*CHAR_BIT) {
        count = POPCOUNT64(bitmap.hi >>> (sizeof (bitmap.hi)*CHAR_BIT - offset));
        // logical right shift to do away with the AND
    }else{
        count = POPCOUNT64(bitmap.hi)+
                POPCOUNT16(bitmap.lo >>> (sizeof (bitmap)*CHAR_BIT - offset));
    }
    return count;
}
```

here there is only 1 branch compared to the 2 you had before (possibly 3 depending on how `MIN` was implemented)